# Determining whether socket.io TCP or HTTP

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, socket.io

This is my node server

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8889);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I am trying to connect to this node server from client side with the help of [**socket.io.js**](http://socket.io/)

I dont have any problem with the connection
My requirement is that I want to create a `TCP` connection to which clients can connect
But how can I know and confirm the server is a `TCP` type or `HTTP` type

Comment: Do you mean you want raw data exchange rather than HTTP formatted communication?

Comment: I know HTTP is a layer built on top of the TCP layer, but what i want is pure TCP connection for better performance in heavy traffic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.IO is a `Lightweight protocol that sits on top of HTTP.`

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec

You can see more info there https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053026/1012381
But in short you can't have raw data connection by the browser.

Comment: Thanks I know it, but what i want is pure TCP connection for better performance in heavy traffic...

Comment: I don't think you can do that with Socket.io.  You'll have to use native sockets, and those can't interact directly with a browser.

Comment: But `socket.io` has a method `net.createServer()`.Is their any way to use `socket.io` to connect to this TCP server

Comment: You might have found it out already, but once the HTTP hand-shake protocol is done, the connection is almost sending raw data. Only 2 frame bytes are used as extra data, the rest is all your data, reaching the minimum overhead you are looking for.