# Is socket io (server) written on top of node js net.Server class?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Well title says most of it.

I was just reading `net.Server` class in node js , and i already know about `socket.io` , it seems like `net.server` class provides direct access to tcp layer , and we can implement sockets directly using this `net.server` class , so is `socket.io` also written using it ?

Or is it written on UDP/Datagram Sockets `class:dgram.Socket` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well u can always have a look at https://github.com/socketio/socket.io as it's open source .

Anyways, from what i infer from source, it's based on `http` neither `net.server` nor `dgram.Socket`
*You can refer source/lib/index.js*

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696903/determining-whether-socket-io-tcp-or-http) says `Socket.IO is a Lightweight protocol that sits on top of HTTP.`

Hope it helps

Comment: ya i had a look at source and s.o link , looks like it's written on Http , still vl keep looking from credible and official sources