# communicating with Python socket server (Chrome extension)

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to write a simple extension in chrome which sends data to a TCP socket server in python.

Unfortunately, extensions cannot use sockets library in chrome.
is there any simple way to communicate with a TCP socket server in python?

Alternatively, is there any way to communicate with python at all?

Comment: read that thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945345/differences-between-tcp-sockets-and-web-sockets-one-more-time

Comment: [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) may help you with communicating with the python script you'll create. Its basically a way for native application to communicate with the Chrome extension. You can read more of it in [this chromium blog](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/10/connecting-chrome-apps-and-extensions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) is what you want.

You can find a example code snippet in the Example section of this page. 
It uses native messaging to communicate with a Python script.