# PHP Socket stucking in accept

Tags: php, sockets

I have a php socket server and a javascript websocket, but websocket stuck in connecting to socket.
There is no error but websocket stay connecting.

sock.php

```
set_time_limit(0);

$ip   = '127.0.0.1';


$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$ret  = socket_bind($sock, $ip);
$ret  = socket_listen($sock);

do 
{
 $ref = socket_accept($sock);

 /*
   Write message
 */
 $msg ="Success receive from client\n";

 socket_write($ref, $msg, strlen($msg));

 /*
   Read message
 */
 $buf = socket_read($ref , 1024);

 echo "Received message: $buf\n";

 socket_close($ref);

}while (true);

socket_close($sock);

?>
```

javascript websocket:

```
var sock = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/sock.php');
sock.onopen(function()
{
 console.log('socket connected.');
});
```

Comment: I do not see any `sock.send`. What do you expect? There is an infinite loop in PHP without any `break`. `$sock` is never closed (not reached). I might not be getting your Q correct.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thanks for replying, I might be wrong but I expected to sock got connected first and then start sending message. I won't get 'sock connected' log.

Comment: I might be wrong as well. So ok, indeed `socket_accept` gives a new resource handling one connection to one client. Unless using forks / processes, you have blocking code. So accept should wait for a connection. If I am right, `socket_read` will block as well until 1024 bytes are received. However, JS does not send anything. `console.log('socket connected.');` actually should be executed as far as I can see. There's nothing in the browser console?

Comment: Try some console output immediately after `socket_accept($sock);` Btw. properly implementing the WebSocket protocol from the scratch on top of a raw socket is a hard task. You should use one of the open source libraries out there in the world. Unfortunately PHP does not provide WebSockets out of the box.

Comment: Ratchet http://socketo.me/ or you might consider diving into node.js programming which has several websocket packages.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the correct port in `socket_bind()` or it will listen on a random port. You check this with `netstat` on Linux and Windows. As you try to connect to `ws://localhost` that should be port 80. However binding to port 80 is usually not allowed, unless you are an admin user. Best to bind to another port, for example 8080, and connect to `ws://localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of trial and error and research, I finally came across this:

Websockets vs TCP socket is the problem. PHP socket_create family of functions only creates the basic low level TCP socket on which Websockets is built on top of. So while your javascript message in console says a websocket is successfully connected after your php script socket_creates and socket_binds, the sockets from JS and PHP are different and cannot mesh with the script_accept cunction. As a result, it gets stuck in an infinite loop trying to accept.

The confusion arises because JS says "websocket successful" which also gave me completely the wrong impression as well. JS only does this because it recognises a legit TCP socket (on which WS is built).. but it doesn't validate the websocket functionality on top of the TCP framework.

Citation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sockets.php
"The socket extension implements a low-level interface to the socket communication functions based on the popular BSD sockets, providing the possibility to act as a socket server as well as a client."
Citation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Client-server_example_using_TCP
"Establishing a TCP server involves the following basic steps:"

This has also been pointed out here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945345/differences-between-tcp-sockets-and-web-sockets-one-more-time#:~:text=In%20fact%2C%20WebSockets%20is%20built,event%20handler%20once%20per%20message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945345/differences-between-tcp-sockets-and-web-sockets-one-more-time#:%7E:text=In%20fact%2C%20WebSockets%20is%20built,event%20handler%20once%20per%20message).