# Why we have WebSockets but have not simple Sockets in Web?

Tags: javascript, html, sockets

So we have Websockets:
`var socket = new WebSocket("ws://some/", ["soap", "wamp"]`

WebSockets are made for lowlatency connect and sending and recieving messages, but why we cant use simple sockets in web, like `var socket = new Socket("tcp://some:6413")` and cant do magic like `socket.sendByte(0xFF)` `socket.readByte()` and etc.

It would discover much more 
opportunities for using it for extra-lowlatency, for sharing images, videos, online HTML5 games for fun..

I know what Flash/Unity/Java can do this, but why JS and HTML5 still didn't do this ? Or did they?

Comment: I think that historicly, JS was invented for simple DOM manipulations, and nothing more. even AJAX is a subsitution for creating an IFrame and reading it's data. I think that in a frontend sense, many front end developer will find socket API very low-level and un-needed. needless to say, in Node.js you got everything, but the browser world is different

Comment: more or less answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051516/how-to-establish-a-tcp-socket-connection-from-a-web-browser-client-side

Comment: 2011, its about 4 years past.. And there is no any plans for doing it native ?