# Why websocket needs an opening handshake using HTTP? Why can't it be an independent protocol?

Tags: http, websocket, protocols

*Websocket is designed in such a way that its servers can share a port with HTTP servers, by having its handshake be a valid HTTP Upgrade request.*

I have a doubt in this design philosophy.
Any ways the WebSocket Protocol is an independent TCP-based protocol.

Why would we need this HTTP handshake(upgrade request) and a protocol switching. Instead why can't we directly(& independently) follow a websocket like protocol?

Comment: Read this: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-1.2

Comment: Hi, I read this already, but it was a bit like finding a needle in a stack of hay. So I would put exact sentence where the answer is hidden "In relatively simple setups with just one IP address and a single server for all traffic to a single hostname, this(HTTP handshaking) might allow a practical way for systems based on the WebSocket Protocol to be deployed."   Ref:http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-1.8

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To quote from the [IETF 6455 WebSocket spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.1):

```
The WebSocket Protocol attempts to address the goals of existing
bidirectional HTTP technologies in the context of the existing HTTP
infrastructure; as such, it is designed to work over HTTP ports 80
and 443 as well as to support HTTP proxies and intermediaries, even
if this implies some complexity specific to the current environment.
However, the design does not limit WebSocket to HTTP, and future
implementations could use a simpler handshake over a dedicated port
without reinventing the entire protocol.
```

In other words, there is a vast infrastructure for HTTP and HTTPS that already exists (proxies, firewalls, caches, and other intermediaries). In order to increase the chances of being adopted widely, the WebSocket protocol was designed to allow adjustments and extensions to the existing infrastructure without having to recreate everything from scratch to support a new protocol on a dedicate port.

It's also important to note that even if WebSocket protocol were to get rid of the HTTP compatible handshake, it would still need a handshake of almost equivalent complexity to support security requirements of the modern web so the browser and server can validate each other and to support CORS (cross-origin request sharing) securely. Even "raw" Flash sockets do a handshake with the server via the security policy request prior to creating the actual socket.

Comment: Was trying to understand the protocol. Your answer was really helpful. I thought of using a new port & application for handling WebSocket. With your answer I think I can use apache to handle WebSocket protocol also. But is there any existing apache module that can process WS data frames? Do you have any suggestion or links that might be helpful for implementing this?

Comment: some websocket extensions expect/assume that websocket is established as an upgrade via an http path (be it HTTP/1.1, SPDY, or HTTP/2). The mux extension, for example, has addChannel logic that expects HTTP requests to function properly.