# Java wesocket not connecting to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

So I have this java websocket server, that is on a separate machine, with no firewall and opened ports:

```java
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(23547);
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();

                    try (
                            BufferedReader serverReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                            Writer serverWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
                    ) {
                        serverWriter.write("hello, " + serverReader.readLine() + "\n");
                        serverWriter.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    throw t;
                }
            }
        });
        serverThread.setDaemon(true);
        serverThread.start();
```

And when trying to listen with javascript, I get this "WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:23547/' failed" instantly, while when trying to access to other random ports it takes 5/8 seconds before throwing an error.

JavaScript code used to connect to the WS:

```js
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:23547");
```

Thank you !

Comment: [TCP sockets are not WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681267/what-is-the-fundamental-difference-between-websockets-and-pure-tcp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ServerSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/net/ServerSocket.html) class doesn't create a WebSocket, but a [TCP socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket). WebSocket is an additional layer with its own protocol requirements.

MDN provides a tutorial on [Writing a WebSocket server in Java](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java) using a `ServerSocket`.

If you're running in a JavaEE 7 compatible container you can use the Java API for WebSocket. Oracle provides a tutorial called ["Java EE 7: Building Web Applications with WebSocket, JavaScript and HTML5"](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html).

There are also numerous third-party libraries available for implementing WebSocket servers. Here are a few examples:

- [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.websockets)
- [Akka HTTP](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html)
- [Jetty](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/WebSockets)